# Mouse icon grab \ grabbing does not work (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fabricjs

When i set the defaultCursor for the canvas, on grab or grabbing mode, the cursor appears with default cursor (Arrow). This only occurs on Chrome, in mozilla works fine.

¿Any suggestion?

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
//canvas.defaultCursor = "grab" -> Not Works (Chrome)
//canvas.defaultCursor = "grabbimg" -> Not Works (Chrome)
canvas.defaultCursor = "pointer" //Works Fine (Chrome, Mozilla)
```

[Fiddle Cursor Chrome Bug!](https://jsfiddle.net/bbg3oeyg/28/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-webkit-grab` for chrome `-moz-grab` for mozilla , check [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor). For standard use `move`

***DEMO*** for chrome

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
//canvas.defaultCursor = "grab" -> Not Works (Chrome)
//canvas.defaultCursor = "grabbimg" -> Not Works (Chrome)

function setCursor(){
  canvas.defaultCursor = "-webkit-grab"
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='setCursor()'>set cursor</button>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi @Durga, On my environment, i have a button, that when i click, i do canvas.defaultCursor = "-webkit-grab". But until i do not click on the canvas, the pointer appears in default mode. see how it works here: https://imgur.com/a/OeLdv4x

Comment: @PedroJose check updated answer, it works for button click.

Comment: Please, see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/7p7njtjm/31/. When i click on grab, as spect, the cursor turns on in grab mode. but, when i do mouse click on the canvas, the mouse should turns on grabbing mode, but it does not doing. ¿Why?